# Previous next buttons on the main page

Tags: support

As the activity on Physics Stack exchange is increasing and steadily, It is getting difficult to browse through questions. Roughly ~ 9 hours or so, the questions disappear from the main page. One is forced to search either using tags, which is somewhat inconvenient and one is likely to miss interesting stuff as one cannot cover every tag.

Firstly is there a way access older questions(~1-3 days) from the main page in an easy way?

Secondly, I propose adding previous and next buttons to the active section of the main page(and perhaps others ), preferably along with numbered pages(roughly covering a weeks activity) that will allow the user to access older questions with ease.

Comment: I generally browse [the "questions page"](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions), where things appear time-ordered and are paged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Firstly is there a way access older questions(~1-3 days) from the main page in an easy way?

[The Questions tab, sorted by "active"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=active)

> Secondly, I propose adding previous and next buttons to the active section of the main page(and perhaps others ), preferably along with numbered pages(roughly covering a weeks activity) that will allow the user to access older questions with ease.

Pagination is already there on the Questions tab (no particular need for forward/back buttons imo).

I don't see a particular need for this, besides, once you reach the end of the main page you already are presented with this message:

[image]

Comment: Thank you that was helpful, I rarely used the questions tab. Perhaps its time.